# Lodash groupBy id of each item of nested array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have the following input as an example of `clubs` that includes a property `players` which is an array of objects.

### Input

```
const clubs = [
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Club Name',
    creatorId: 10,
    players: [
      {
        userId: 2, // group by this property
        name: 'Player name 1',
        clubId: 5,
      },
      {
        userId: 7, // group by this property
        name: 'Player name 2',
        clubId: 5,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Club Name 2',
    creatorId: 2,
    players: [
      {
        userId: 7, // group by this property
        name: 'Player name 3',
        clubId: 6,
      },
      {
        userId: 8, // group by this property
        name: 'Player name 4',
        clubId: 6,
      },
      {
        userId: 22, // group by this property
        name: 'Player name 5',
        clubId: 6,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want to `groupBy` each of the `player.userId`s of each club and should have a value of the club for each player, to have the following output.

### Desired Output

```
{
  '2': [{ id: 5, name: 'Club Name', creatorId: 10, players: [Array] }],
  '7': [
    { id: 5, name: 'Club Name', creatorId: 10, players: [Array] },
    { id: 6, name: 'Club Name 2', creatorId: 2, players: [Array] },
  ],
  '8': [{ id: 6, name: 'Club Name 2', creatorId: 2, players: [Array] }],
  '22': [{ id: 6, name: 'Club Name 2', creatorId: 2, players: [Array] }],
};
```

I have tried

```
const byPlayer = allClubs.reduce((b, a) => {
  a.players.forEach((player) => {
    const id = player.clubId;
    const clubsByPlayer = b[id] || (b[id] = []);
    clubsByPlayer.push(a);
  });
  return b;
}, {});
```

But it returned the group by the `clubId` and a value of each player in the club

```
{
  '5': [
    { id: 5, name: 'Club Name', creatorId: 10, players: [Array] },
    { id: 5, name: 'Club Name', creatorId: 10, players: [Array] },
  ],
  '6': [
    { id: 6, name: 'Club Name 2', creatorId: 2, players: [Array] },
    { id: 6, name: 'Club Name 2', creatorId: 2, players: [Array] },
    { id: 6, name: 'Club Name 2', creatorId: 2, players: [Array] },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
const id = player.clubId;
```

with

```
const id = player.userId;
```

```js
const
    clubs = [{ id: 5, name: 'Club Name', creatorId: 10, players: [{ userId: 2, name: 'Player name 1', clubId: 5 }, { userId: 7, name: 'Player name 2', clubId: 5 }] }, { id: 6, name: 'Club Name 2', creatorId: 2, players: [{ userId: 7, name: 'Player name 3', clubId: 6 }, { userId: 8, name: 'Player name 4', clubId: 6 }, { userId: 22, name: 'Player name 5', clubId: 6 }] }],
    byPlayer = clubs.reduce((b, a) => {
        a.players.forEach((player) => {
            (b[player.userId] ??= []).push(a);
        });
        return b;
    }, {});

console.log(byPlayer)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This groups by the correct property, but the value of each property is the player and not the club, so I think I do need to `push(a)`

Comment: sorry, please see edit.